# Create services taking reference of existing subscription

Tags: azure-cloud-services

Is it possible to take the existing services in azure cloud subscription as reference and create similar services with parameters update in another subscription either by using powershell or ARM template.
We are missing few details while taking the reference details manually and then creating it using ARM templates. We wanted it to be end to end automation.

Comment: You could just create a copy of the cloud service in Visual Studio and deploy it with any updated parameters to the other subscription .

Answer (score 0):

You can export the ARM template from existing resources using Export-AzureRmResourceGroup or Save-AzureRmResourceGroupDeploymentTemplate (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-template/) and then redeploy that template to a new environment.

However, if you are using Export-AzureRmResourceGroup to try to dynamically create an ARM template from existing resources then the generated template will likely not be ready to automatically redeploy.  There may be issues with resource dependencies, resources not getting exported correctly, template limitations, etc.  It will take a fair bit of manual effort to update the generated ARM template to get it to a point where it can be correctly redeployed into another subscription.

If you are able to use Save-AzureRmResourceGroupDeploymentTemplate (ie. if your existing resources were all deployed via ARM templates with no post deployment ad-hoc changes) then the templates should be ready to deploy.

For future reference, the best solution is to always deploy all of your resources via ARM templates (or something like Terraform) where your configuration is all saved in a source repository and you are deploying via a CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Currently we are adopting the best solution which you have mentioned in your comment. But was looking for any other ways to do which can give better than this.